# Isabelle structure proof

Tags: functional-programming, isabelle, hol

There is a set of some structures. I'm trying to prove that the cardinality of the set equals some number. Full theory is too long to post here. So here is a simplified one just to show the idea.

Let the objects (which I need to count) are sets containing natural numbers from 1 to n.  The idea of the proof is as follows. I define a function which transforms sets to lists of 0 and 1. Here is the function and its inverse:

```
fun set_to_bitmap :: "nat set ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
  "set_to_bitmap xs x 0 = []"
| "set_to_bitmap xs x (Suc n) =
    (if x ∈ xs then Suc 0 else 0) # set_to_bitmap xs (Suc x) n"

fun bitmap_to_set :: "nat list ⇒ nat ⇒ nat set" where
  "bitmap_to_set [] n = {}"
| "bitmap_to_set (x#xs) n =
    (if x = Suc 0 then {n} else {}) ∪ bitmap_to_set xs (Suc n)"

value "set_to_bitmap {1,3,7,8} 1 8"
value "bitmap_to_set (set_to_bitmap {1,3,7,8} 1 8) 1"
```

Then I plan to prove that 1) a number of 0/1 lists with length n equals `2^^n`,
2) the functions are bijections,
3) so the cardinality of the original set is `2^^n` too.

Here are some auxiliary definitions and lemmas, which seems useful:

```
definition "valid_set xs n ≡ (∀a. a ∈ xs ⟶ 0 < a ∧ a ≤ n)"
definition "valid_bitmap ps n ≡ length ps = n ∧ set ps ⊆ {0, Suc 0}"

lemma length_set_to_bitmap:
  "valid_set xs n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   length (set_to_bitmap xs x n) = n"
  apply (induct xs x n rule: set_to_bitmap.induct)
  apply simp
  sorry

lemma bitmap_members:
  "valid_set xs n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   set_to_bitmap xs x n = ps ⟹
   set ps ⊆ {0, Suc 0}"
  apply (induct xs x n arbitrary: ps rule: set_to_bitmap.induct)
  apply simp
  sorry

lemma valid_set_to_valid_bitmap:
  "valid_set xs n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   set_to_bitmap xs x n = ps ⟹
   valid_bitmap ps n"
  unfolding valid_bitmap_def
  using bitmap_members length_set_to_bitmap by auto

lemma valid_bitmap_to_valid_set:
  "valid_bitmap ps n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   bitmap_to_set ps x = xs ⟹
   valid_set xs n"
  sorry

lemma set_to_bitmap_inj:
  "valid_set xs n ⟹
   valid_set xy n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   set_to_bitmap xs x n = ps ⟹
   set_to_bitmap ys x n = qs ⟹
   ps = qs ⟹
   xs = ys"
  sorry

lemma set_to_bitmap_surj:
  "valid_bitmap ps n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   ∃xs. set_to_bitmap xs x n = ps"
  sorry

lemma bitmap_to_set_to_bitmap_id:
  "valid_set xs n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   bitmap_to_set (set_to_bitmap xs x n) x = xs"
  sorry

lemma set_to_bitmap_to_set_id:
  "valid_bitmap ps n ⟹
   x = Suc 0 ⟹
   set_to_bitmap (bitmap_to_set ps x) x n = ps"
  sorry
```

Here is a final lemma:

```
lemma valid_set_size:
  "card {xs. valid_set xs n} = 2 ^^ n"
```

Does this approach seem valid? Are there any examples of such a proof? Could you suggest an idea on how to prove the lemmas? I'm stuck because the induction with `set_to_bitmap.induct` seems to be not applicable here.

Comment: Note that the Isabelle Zulip (https://isabelle.zulipchat.com) is also a good place to ask questions like these and maybe have somebody have a look at what you're doing and if it makes sense/if you're making your life harder than it has to be.

Comment: Not to detract from StackOverflow, but I think StackOverflow is more suitable to short, clear questions of general interest and not so much highly specific questions of the ‘Please have a look at my code and tell me if it makes sense’ type. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, that kind of approach does work: if you have a function `f` from a set `A` to a set `B` and an inverse function to it, you can prove `bij_betw f A B` (read: `f` is a bijection from `A` to `B`), and that then implies `card A = card B`.

However, there are a few comments that I have:

1. You should use `bool` lists instead of `nat` lists if you can only have 0 or 1 in them anyway.
2. It is usually better to use existing library functions than to define new ones yourself. Your two functions could be defined using library functions like this:

   ````
   set_to_bitmap :: nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat set ⇒ bool list
   set_to_bitmap x n A = map (λi. i ∈ A) [x..<x+n]

   bitmap_to_set :: nat ⇒ bool list ⇒ nat set
   bitmap_to_set n xs = (λi. i + n) ` {i. i < length xs ∧ xs ! i}```
   ````
3. Side note: I would use upper-case letters for sets, not something like `xs` (which is usually used for lists).
4. Perhaps this is because you simplified your problem, but in its present form, `valid_set A n` is simply the same as `A ⊆ {1..n}` and the `{A. valid_set A n}` is simply `Pow {1..n}`. The cardinality of that is easy to show with results from the library:

   ```
   lemma "card (Pow {1..(n::nat)}) = 2 ^ n"
     by (simp add: card_Pow)`
   ```

As for your original questions: Your first few lemmas are provable, but for the induction to go through, you have to get rid of some of the unneeded assumptions first. The `x = Suc 0` is the worst one – there is no way you can use induction if you have that as an assumption, because as soon as you do one induction step, you increase `x` by 1 and so you won't be able to apply your induction hypothesis. The following versions of your first three lemmas go through easily:

```
lemma length_set_to_bitmap:
  "length (set_to_bitmap xs x n) = n"
  by (induct xs x n rule: set_to_bitmap.induct) auto

lemma bitmap_members:
  "set (set_to_bitmap xs x n) ⊆ {0, Suc 0}"
  by (induct xs x n rule: set_to_bitmap.induct) auto

lemma valid_set_to_valid_bitmap: "valid_bitmap (set_to_bitmap xs x n) n"
  unfolding valid_bitmap_def
  using bitmap_members length_set_to_bitmap by auto
```

I also recommend not adding "abbreviations" like `ps = set_to_bitmap xs x n` as an assumption. It doesn't break anything, but it tends to complicate things needlessly.

The next lemma is a bit trickier. Due to your recursive definitions, you have to generalise the lemma first (`valid_bitmap` requires the set to be in the range from `1` to `n`, but once you make one induction step it has to be from `2` to `n`). The following works:

```
lemma valid_bitmap_to_valid_set_aux:
  "bitmap_to_set ps x ⊆ {x..<x + length ps}"
  by (induction ps x rule: bitmap_to_set.induct)
     (auto simp: valid_bitmap_def valid_set_def)

lemma valid_bitmap_to_valid_set:
  "valid_bitmap ps n ⟹ valid_set (bitmap_to_set ps 1) n"
  using valid_bitmap_to_valid_set_aux unfolding valid_bitmap_def valid_set_def
  by force
```

Injectivity and surjectivity (which is your ultimate goal) should follow from the fact that the two are inverse functions. Proving that will probably be doable with induction, but will require a few generalisations and auxiliary lemmas. It should be easier if you stick to the non-recursive definition using library functions that I sketched above.